# Cheapest, future-scalable way to host a HTTPS PHP Website on AWS?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I've already got an RDS instance configured and running, but currently we're still running on our old web host. We'd like to decrease latency by hosting the code within AWS.

Two concerns:
1) Future scalability
2) Redundancy ... not a huge concern but AWS does occasionally go down.

Has anyone had this problem where they just need to cheaply run what is essentially a database interface via a language such as PHP/Ruby, in 2 regions? (with one as a failover)

Does Amazon offer something that automatically manages resources, that's also cost effective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon's [Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) service supports both PHP and Ruby apps natively, and allows you to scale your app servers automatically.

In a second region, run a slave RDS instance off of your master (easy to set up in RDS) and have another beanstalk setup there ready as a failover.

Comment: Do they offer two way master/slave syncing with RDS ... or would the slave in the second region have to be readonly during a failover?

Comment: Also, the costs for Beanstalk seem a bit high. ~$30 typical base for a simple application? Really? Are these costs typical or does it start out much lower?

Comment: Yeah, let's look at the cost breakdown. The beanstalk itself is free - it's just the glue. The load balancer costs $18.00. If you had an instance doing the load balancer you would need at least an m1.small, which would cost around $60. So for $18 you get a good deal on ELB.

Then it's about the m1.micro instance they quote in the base offering. If you want a scalable site, you won't be using these, because they have both throughput and CPU limitations that can cause lag on websites. <cont>

Comment: So if you want to start smaller, you can skip the load balancer and just start with an instance. Then when you start to grow and need scalability, no problem - just add on a load balancer and more servers when you need it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, I just realized that you can do a minimal beanstalk and stay within the [free tier](http://aws.amazon.com/pricing/elasticbeanstalk/), if you are a new AWS customer. Free is always a good way to start!